# Radio Button Does Not Unchecked When Clicking On Itself

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a radio button like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="attr_var" class="minimal">
Add To Attribute
```

Users can properly click on it for checking it, but it does not unchecked when it's re-clicked.

Basically when it's checked, users can be uncheck it when they re-click on it but this does not workout.

So how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are distinct from checkboxes. The user can change options between a set of radio buttons, but it cannot be deselected.

You can refer to [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13513) answer for a better explanation as to **Why is it impossible to deselect HTML "radio" inputs?**

PS. This applies to *native* HTML radio buttons. You can still use a checkbox for this purpose, or create your own buttons with CSS and Javascript that behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just single option to be check or uncheck, use ***Checkbox*** instead of *Radio button*.

For example,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="attr_var" class="minimal"> Add To Attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons can't be unchecked, I think you just need a checkbox which you can check or uncheck.

Please find the reference here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="attr_var" class="minimal">
Add To Attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
    Default checked radio
  </label>
</div>
```